# Hex-Rays Unexpected dyld_opcode in the debugger server

Tags: debugging, macos

I'm using IDA Pro 6.1 on OS X 10.7.2, and I'm trying to use the mac_server (32-bit) as my remote debugger, although encounter this error:

```
Unexpected dyld_opcode in the debugger server (init_dylib): 216df00
```

I've changed the permissions on the server to procmod, etc. and the server starts up fine:

```
IDA Mac OS X 32-bit remote debug server(MT) v1.14. Hex-Rays (c) 2004-2011
Listening on port #23946...
```

How do I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant code is to be found in the IDA SDK in mac_debmod.cpp, 
`void mac_debmod_t::init_dylib(ea_t addr, const char *fname).`

This fires when a library is loaded and compares the opcodes it gets to `1E FF 2F E1`. If the opcodes don't match this error is fired.

I'll see how to fix this, will post updates here.

Comment: Been away on vacation since I posted this. Just got back. Will give it a try within a week or so. ;)